# Query on DynamoDB Provisioned Throughput WCU/RCU operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to understand how dynamo DB provisioned throughput (RCU/WCU) works.

I tried 2 scenarios where i made a change in WCU ( 1,000 & 10,000), but the WCU consumed figures which i am getting is same i.e. 809.63.

In a nutshell, i have 123 records distributed in 5 files, each record is of 400 KB ( according to dynamo db limit rule). When executing these cases there was no throttling, and strange thing is script execution time is same i.e. 6 sec, even though i have changed WCU count to 1k & 10k respectively.

My question is why does it behave like this. I would like to know your comments on this.

My assumption is if i decrease/increase WCU count, i should see changes in script execution time, which is not in my case.

Dynamo DB Scenario tests:

[image: Dynamo DB Scenario tests]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WCU/RCU do not increase the speed of a DynamoDB SDK response time, they only set an upper limit for capacity usage.**

Read and Write Capacity Units are, as the name suggests, **capacity units**. They indicate the upper limit of how much capacity your table can handle in terms of read/write. What this means is, in your case since you are using 809.63 WCU, if your WCU is set to above 810 then you won't get any throttled requests. However, if you lower your WCU to 800, you will start seeing your requests being throttled.

If you have consistent TPS and know how many capacity units you will be using, then set just the amount that you will require. In your case, 1k WCU seems sufficient and will not make any difference compared to 10k in terms of performance, **unless you use more than 1k WCU**, in which case you can provision more capacity or implement auto-scaling to handle it.

See here for more information: [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html#HowItWorks.ProvisionedThroughput.Manual)

Edit: As discussed in below comments, if you use more capacity than is provisioned, DynamoDB will temporarily allow a burst of capacity to support it for up to 5 minutes, which could lead to varying results in terms of throttling

Comment: Hi @deiv How to calculate what wcu to provision? And 10000 was recommended by capacity calculator present in dynamodb console.How to calculate wcu?

Comment: You can get an estimate using their calculator, but the best way is to do it the way you did it by running some tests and getting a better idea of the capacity you are actually using, since it highly depends on the speed at which you are calling the SDK (in your case it took 6 seconds to make the required calls)

Comment: Hi @Deiv I do not agree with the above comments, because when i kept WCU as 500, i am still getting the same results.                                                          In addition i have 2 more queries:  
1)  Dynamo DB charges- How does it work? Does it charge on capacity consumed or capacity provisioned?
2)  For DynamoDB the pricing page says  that it's metered hourly. Does that mean that it's the average amount provisioned throughout that hour? Or the total number of instances of units provisioned?

Comment: That means you aren't actually consuming 800 WCU, can you go into the DynamoDB metrics and see what the actual values are? if it is actually a consistent 800 WCU, you will get throttled if you only provision 500.

For pricing, DynamoDB has two pricing models, one is for provisioned capacity, and one is for on-demand. Provisioned capacity is a per hour of the total number of provision capacity, regardless of if you use it or not. On-demand pricing is per million requests.

Comment: I have a graph which says provisioned is 500 and consumed is 809.63. For some security reasons i cannot share the image with you. i have doubled check from DDB metrics page and i can see the WCU value as 500.

Comment: Ah okay I get what you're seeing, sorry it slipped my mind earlier. DynamoDB has a burst limit, in which it will handle all capacity going over your provisioned capacity for 5 minutes bursts only. So, if you have consumed 809.63 for over 5 minutes, then it will throttle them. See more info here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-design.html#bp-partition-key-throughput-bursting

Comment: Hi @Deiv, Now this makes sense and a good point to note. I will answer the question separately. Many thanks for looking into this :)

Comment: No problem, let me know if you have any more questions! Also, feel free to select my answer as the answer to the question using the checkmark, so that the question is marked as solved and others can better refer to it

Comment: Hi Deiv, you have not mentioned burst capacity in your main answer but its in the comment section. Do you still want me to mark your main answer as correct or you will be editing ur main answer?

Comment: Good point, I have added it as a note in the main answer for reference

Answer (score 1):

Before answering, many Thanks to Deiv & Stu for finding this evidence.
DynamoDB can consume up to 300 seconds of unused throughput in burst capacity.

The maximum item size in DynamoDB is 400KB and 1 RCU gives you a read of up to 4KB.

Lets say you want to read an item that is 400KB in size and you have 1 RCU on your table. You could retrieve that item once every 100 seconds.

Because of burst capacity there will always be a time you can read that item, because in fact you can use up to 300 RCUs in one go, not just 1.

Imagine starting the table with that 400KB item. You need to wait 100 seconds without spending any RCUs so that you've earned enough burst capacity to get the item. After 101 seconds you make the request, spend 100 RCUs and get the item. After another 5 seconds you make the request again, but get denied with a Throttling Exception.

So no, DynamoDB will not increase request latency to meet your RCU provision. It either returns your results as fast as possible, or throws an exception.